# From edge-disjoint paths to independent paths

Tags: reference-request, graph-theory, co.combinatorics

Let $\mathcal{G}_k$ denote the set of all graphs that contain two vertices $x,y$
and $k$ edge-disjoint $x-y$ paths.

Define $f(k)$ to be the maximum such that for every graph $G\in \mathcal{G}_k$
there are two vertices $x',y'$ with $f(k)$ independent $x'-y'$ paths in $G$.

Here, a set of paths is *independent* if none contains an internal vertex of another.

Are any lower bounds for $f(k)$ known in the literature?

In particular, I need $f(3)=3$ in an algorithm where I need to find some obstructions in a graph.
This is not hard to prove, but I'm wondering whether it is known in the literature, maybe as a special case of a more general theorem.

As a different formulation, how large can you make $f(k)$ in the following statement?

> If $G$ is an undirected graph containing two vertices $x,y$ and $k$ edge-disjoint $x-y$ paths, then $G$ contains two vertices $x',y'$ with $f(k)$ independent $x'-y'$ paths.

Comment: $f(k)$ is a maximum of what? What quantity does it denote?

Comment: Some doubts: in a graph $G \in \mathcal{G}_k$, are other non $k$ edge-disjoint paths allowed between $x$ and $y$? A graph $G \in \mathcal{G}_k$ must contain *at least* one pair of vertices $x$ and $y$ connected with $k$ disjoint edges? or *exactly one* pair? What about a graph that contais a pair of vertices connected with $k$ disjoint edges and also a pair of vertices connected with $k+1$ disjoint edges?

Comment: Apologies, I corrected the definition of $f(k)$.

Comment: I could be mistaken but it seems that the well-known series parallel graph (the recursive diamond graph, see cseweb.ucsd.edu/~dasgupta/254-embeddings/claire.pdf) can be used to show that $f(k) = 2$ for any value of $k$.

Comment: @ChandraChekuri: Actually, for the diamond graph $G_2$, we have two vertices $s,t$ with $4$ edge-disjoint $s-t$ paths, but we have 3 independent $x'-y'$ paths, where $x'=s$ and $y'$ is one of the 2 degree-4 vertices besides $s$ and $t$. I believe that these graphs can be used, though, to show that $f(k)=3$ for any $k\ge 3$.

Comment: Maybe one of you could write an answer with this argument.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It turns out that $f(k)=3$ for all $k\ge 3$. Recursive diamond graphs are extremal. See [arXiv:1203.4483](http://arxiv.org/abs/1203.4483) for a proof.

Comment: yippee. a cstheory.SE citation :)